# Timeout error when connecting to Azure database in Azure Databricks

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks

Step1: Install the ODBC driver 17 using below script in Databricks

```
%sh 

curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list 
apt-get update
ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17
apt-get -y install unixodbc-dev
sudo apt-get install python3-pip -y
pip3 install --upgrade pyodbc
```

Step 2: Tried to connect to Azure database using active directory integrated authentication.

```
%python

import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect( 'Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:xxxxxxx.database.windows.net,1433;Database=xxxxxxx;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=60;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryIntegrated')
#result = conn.execute("select 1+1 as res")
result = conn.execute("select * from tablename")
print (result)
conn.close()
```

The above Python code is working fine in my local system and getting the below timeout error when execute in Azure Databricks. Please help on this issue.

```
OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Answer (score 0):

If your cluster has option "Enable table access control and only allow Python and SQL commands" enabled, then you need to put port 1433 into the list of ports in the Spark configuration option `spark.databricks.pyspark.iptable.outbound.whitelisted.ports` (see [documentation](https://docs.databricks.com/security/access-control/table-acls/table-acl.html#python-and-sql-table-access-control)).

Otherwise, you need to check firewall rules between Databricks instance & SQL database - missing rule for port 1433 is most often the reason for such errors.  Execute

```
%sh

nc -zv your_sqlserver_host 1433
```

to check that you can connect to the server

Comment: Thank you. It's working through SQL server authentication.